# Completely functional Cat 5e cable limited to 100 Mbps?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

Cable in question connects two floors of a house, total length shouldn't be more than 100 feet but its path would make it extremely painful to replace, so we're investigating all other options first.

We used a network cable tester and verified that all 8 pins are properly connected and in the right sequence, and everything seems to be in order on that front. The cable itself is definitely Cat 5e, at least according to its outer labeling.

The cable is connected to a gigabit ethernet switch, which is in turn connected to a Sonicwall. Every outgoing connection from said switch is running at 1000 Mbps except for this one.

We have tried switching which port it is connected to in the switch, and the result is always the same. On the other end, we have tried plugging in a 2018 Lenovo laptop, an older gigabit Netgear switch, and an AirPort Time Capsule. All of these devices negotiated to 100 Mbps. Furthermore, all of these devices negotiated to 1 Gbps when plugged directly into the switch using a different cable while sitting next to it.

I'm 100% confident that the network tester isn't faulty, so what gives? The only possible explanations I can think of are either (1) the cable is not truly Cat 5e, or (2) there is a nearly-severed connection  in one of the pins somewhere along the wire that creates a point of high resistivity. I suppose its possible that our network tester operates at a high enough voltage that the other end is still able to pick it up, but the normal operating voltage (5V, is it?) isn't high enough to register as HIGH on the receiving end. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Unless you have an expensive network tester, then you only have test results for DC voltage levels. DC measurements only indicate basic connectivity, but the actual bandwidth is unknown. DC voltage is capable of zero information transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cheap pinout tester can't tell if you have a split pair, and a split pair could do this. Double check how you've wired each end.